# setting css of axis in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Is there away to do .axis path { fill : none } in d3.js?

I've tried .attr and .style on .call(d3.svg.axis() but to no avail. I just be doing something wrong here...

The full code which I'm using to create my axes is below:

```
 // create Axis
  svg.selectAll("axis")
      .data(d3.range(angle.domain()[1]))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + angle(d) * 180 / Math.PI + ")"; })
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(radius.copy().range([0,0]))
      .ticks(1)
      .tickFormat("")
      .orient("left"))
      .attr("fill","none") // EDITED WITH FILL NONE
    .append("text") 
      .attr("y", 
        function (d) {
          if (window.innerWidth < 455){
            console.log("innerWidth less than 455: ",window.innerWidth);
            return -(0);
          }
          else{
            console.log("innerWidth greater than 455: ",window.innerWidth);
            return -(0);
          }
        })
      .attr("dy", "0em");
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and in what way does it not work?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I would like to append some css to my axes to replicate .axis path { fill: none} which is currently inline in an html file. I want to replace the inline css with d3 attr or style

Comment: Have you tried adding `.attr("fill", "none")` directly to the axis path?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have that isn't working?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff just tried it and I get the response has "no method 'attr'"

Comment: Can you give the exact code you're trying to run? It seems to be working for me.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the exact code is now above. Thanks

Comment: Try moving setting the fill up to where you're setting the class. FYI, code like that (setting the class) is working fine for me. Could you put a complete example on JSFiddle or something like that?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff going to be hard to put this up on jsFiddle, my project is honestly quite convoluted because I'm trying to support this vis for an older browser...I've tried putting .attr("fill", "none;") just below class, just above it, above .data, and nothing's working. Are you sure you've gotten yours to work?? Thanks.

Comment: Here's exactly what I've tried: after `.call(axis)`, I did a `.selectAll("path")` and set the attributes on that. This works without problems for me. There're various other ways as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I want to apply CSS settings to d3 elements, I find that it is easiest to assign them an ID or class (which you do above), and then apply the desired attributes using CSS.  For example, keep the JS as above, and then in css do:

```
.axis path {

    fill:           none;
}
```

If you want to do it in the JS, you should use:

```
.style('fill', 'none')
```

However, you should apply it to the svg which contains the axis, not inside the .call(d3.svg.axis()).  Hope this helps.